# iOS Today Widget Universal Links From Lock Screen and Notification Center

Tags: swift, today-extension, ios12, ios-universal-links

We have a today widget to deep link into the app. The deep links work just fine when the user accesses the widget from the home screen. However, when a user accesses the widget when the device is locked, or when the user slides down from the top of the screen, the links open in Safari.

I was wondering if anyone else has come across this issue, and if so, how they solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the solution we came upon (Swift 4.1). We needed to support a custom URL scheme to tell iOS that we can open links from the today widget. This uses a different UIApplication delegate function. Along with implementing  `func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool`, we also need to implement `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool`

First, in `Info.plist`, we have our supported schemes under `CFBUndleURLTypes`.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>todayWidgetScheme</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Then, also in `Info.plist`, we also listed the scheme under `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>todayWidgetScheme</string>
</array>
```

Next, when opening the link from the today widget, set the url scheme to the iOS recognized todayWidgetScheme.

```
func openAppFromTodayWidget() {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://url.com") {
        var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)
        components?.scheme = "todayWidgetScheme"

        if let todayWidgetUrl = components?.url {
            extensionContext?.open(todayWidgetUrl)
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in `AppDelegate.swift`, when iOS asks the application to handle the universal link, set the original url scheme

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if url.scheme == "todayWidgetScheme" {
        var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)
        components?.scheme = "https"

        if let todayWidgetUrl = components?.url {
            // do your thing
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```